# Delete product from Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, backend, delete

I want to know how to delete product from Magento 2.2.4 in the admin store? I don't find the section and all answers I found on internet are with PHP code.

Comment: How do we restore the products id after deleting?

Comment: What do you mean restore ?

Comment: I you mean delete ID 14 , create new product with ID 14, that's not possible, database are not working like this. Possibly due to autoincrement (I know because I've had the same question a few times ago ^^)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137033)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137033)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete a single product or several products at once by going to Admin, Catalog, Products, then ticking the checkbox next to each product to delete. Then select 'Delete' from the 'Actions' drop-down menu.

There is a more detailed description of working with the Manage Products grid in the Magento 2 User Guide, which I strongly recommend:
https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/products.html

Answer (score 1):

You can delete product from admin by following steps:

> Step 1: Goto admin Catalog -> Products
>
> Step 2: Select product which you want to delete by checkbox
>
> Step 3: Then select delete from Action dropdown like screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to :

> Catalog -> product -> select product which you want to delete by check checkbox -> Click action dropdown and select "Delete" Option.